# Return json by default using ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

Is it possible to return json by default from the ASP.NET Web API instead of XML?

Comment: This sort of breaks the pattern of keeping the web api agnostic. If you send an `Accept : application/json` in the headers of your ajax request, WebAPI will respond in Json. Can I see your ajax request?

Comment: Thanks mate. Thats all I needed. I just seen a video tutorial from pluralsight using the web api and the bloke put in the api url route and it responded with json straight in the browser. So there was no ajax request. It was only website.com/api/control

Comment: You shouldn't even need the Accept header. If you don't have an Accept header on a GET request, you should get JSON back from WebAPI.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's what is done by default. `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` is registered as the first `MediaTypeFormatter` and if the client doesn't request the response in a specific format, ASP.NET Web API pipeline gives you the response in `application/json` format.

If what you want is to only support `application/json`, remove all other formatters and only leave `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`:

```
public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config) {

    var jqueryFormatter = config.Formatters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter));
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter);
    config.Formatters.Remove(jqueryFormatter);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

@tugberk's solution doesn't really accomplish the goal of changing the default formatter.  It simply makes JSON the *only* option.  If you want to make JSON the default and still support all of the other types, you can do the following:

```
public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config) {
    // move the JSON formatter to the front of the line
    var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    config.Formatters.Remove(jsonFormatter);
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonFormatter);
}
```

Note: JSON is the default formatter as of Web API 2.0.

Comment: Works for me.  Much better.